# How can I make a if else statement on SQL?

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi Guys I'm having a Problem on how i could make a if else statement on SQL,
It only displays the value of rent.rent_status = 1 on a Modal, but if rent.rent_status has no value the modal wont display, how can i make it display?
Here is my code for your reference;

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stall 
        LEFT JOIN tenant ON tenant.stall_id = stall.stall_id 
        LEFT JOIN rent ON rent.tenant_id = tenant.tenant_id
        WHERE rent.rent_status = 1 AND stall.stall_id = 1";
```

Comment: `.. but if rent.rent_status has no value`. It will not display it cause your query has `AND` in it and it expects to get value for both `rent_status` and `stall_id`.

Comment: sorry sir but I cant understand what you mean,

Comment: Sir your sql statement has `AND` in it and when you run the query it searches for `rent_status` and `stall_id` with value 1 and when one of the value is missing in that case it gives empty value.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri yes sir I know that it will not display if rent_status has no value, That's why I'm asking on how could i Display.

Comment: You can remove the `AND` from query and in the `$sql` variable you will get the output and from there you can use `if` `else` in php to handle that part.

Comment: SQL ``if`` ``else`` statement is ``CASE``. Not really sure why you would need it in your scenario but here it is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `LEFT JOIN` and then undoing the outer join in the `WHERE` clause.  You need to move the conditions to the appropriate `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM stall s LEFT JOIN
     tenant t 
     ON t.stall_id = s.stall_id LEFT JOIN
     rent r
     ON r.tenant_id = t.tenant_id AND r.rent_status = 1
WHERE s.stall_id = 1;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table along with matching rows in the second table.  If there is no match, then the values are `NULL` for the columns in the second table.  Your `WHERE` condition fails on `NULL` conditions.

Comment: Sir what is that s on SELECT *
FROM stall s LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Ronnel.D . . . It is called a table alias.  It makes queries easier to write and to read, and is required for expressing certain relationships in queries.

Comment: sir the modal display properly if the value of rent_status is 1 or NULL. but still i  have a problem, since the code is AND it displays both the NULL value and rent_status with VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Wrapping your output with code similar to this

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){'output goes here'}
}
```

I'm not sure how you're using your php , this is just to give you an idea to grow on.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You don't need to use if..else just use or operator....   


SELECT * FROM stall 
                LEFT JOIN tenant ON tenant.stall_id = stall.stall_id 
                LEFT JOIN rent ON rent.tenant_id = tenant.tenant_id
                WHERE ((rent.rent_status = 1) OR (rent.rent_status IS NULL)) AND stall.stall_id = 1"
```

Comment: it is still the same sir, if the value of rent_status is null it will not display the modal,